# How to SUM two column in My SQL left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

So i have table Project

```
---------------------------------
project_id   |     name| 
---------------------------------
     1            | project 1  | 
     2            | project 2  | 
---------------------------------
```

table 02 report

```
----------------------------------------------------
report_id    |     report_emp       | report_hours |report_project_id|   
---------------------------------------------------
  1          |         1            |       5    |        1        | 
  2          |         2            |       7    |        1        | 
  3          |         1            |       9    |        2        | 
  4          |         2            |       6    |        1        | 
  5          |         3            |       8    |        2        | 
--------------------------------------------------
```

and table 03 emp

```
 ----------------------------------------------
emp_id       |  emp_hourly_cost   |      name  | 
-----------------------------------------------
    1        |         8.5        |       A    | 
    2        |         10         |       B    | 
    3        |         12         |       C    | 
    4        |         9          |       D    | 
    5        |         7.5        |       D    | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

as a final result i wanted to get this table

```
---------------------------------------------
     project     |    hours    |  total cost | 
---------------------------------------------
       1         |      18     |       172.5    | 
       2         |      17     |       172.5    | 
---------------------------------------------
```

until now  i only got the project with total hours but not total cost in this statement

```
SELECT * from projects left join(select sum(report_hours ) as hours , daily_reports_project_id 
     from project_id group by report_id)x on x.report_project_id= projects.project_id;
```

total cost  would be sum of all >  [total hours of the project  of the emp in table 2 * emp_hourly_cost   in table 3  ]

i appreciation the help.

Comment: How do you get  50 hours for project 1?

Comment: It's just a demo data actually it  should be 18 hours for project 1

Comment: Then edit your question with the correct expected output because the current one is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT p.project_id project,
       SUM(r.report_hours) hours,
       SUM(r.report_hours * e.emp_hourly_cost) total_cost
FROM project p
LEFT JOIN report r ON r.report_project_id = p.project_id
LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.emp_id = r.report_emp
GROUP BY project_id;
```

If there are projects without reports and you want to get `0` instead of `NULL` as result use also `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT p.project_id project,
       COALESCE(SUM(r.report_hours), 0) hours,
       COALESCE(SUM(r.report_hours * e.emp_hourly_cost), 0) total_cost
FROM project p
LEFT JOIN report r ON r.report_project_id = p.project_id
LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.emp_id = r.report_emp
GROUP BY project_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3L_CsjE-).

Comment: Perfect working charmly, Thank you very much for this. 

how can i improve my self sql like this any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
SELECT sum(column_name1 + column_name2) as 'Total'

- This line is selecting the sum of column_name1 and column_name2 from table1, and giving it an alias of 'Total'

FROM table1

- This line is specifying that we want data from table1

LEFT JOIN table2

- This line is joining table1 with table2 using a LEFT JOIN. This means that all data from table1 will be included, even if there is no matching data in table2

ON table1.column_name1 = table2.column_name2;

- This line is specifying the conditions for the join. In this case, it is saying that column_name1 from table1 should match column_name2 from table2

```
SELECT sum(column_name1 + column_name2) as 'Total'
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name1 = table2.column_name2;
```

Comment: Thank you but needed to calculate total cost for every project despite the changed value for every hour according to the emp who provided the hours worked in the project